# How to break a long line with math operators?

Tags: c

For example

```
int abcdefghijklmn = aaaaaaaaaaaa   / bbbaaaaaaaa   * ccccaaaaaaaa   - aaaaaaaaaaaa * asdfasdfasdfasdf;
```

where to break?

Is there any guidance to do that?

Or is it safe to break anywhere?

```
int abcdefghijklmn = aaaaaaaaaaaa   / 
   bbbaaaaaaaa   * ccccaaaaaaaa   - aaaaaaaaaaaa * asdfasdfasdfasdf;


int abcdefghijklmn = aaaaaaaaaaaa 
   /   bbbaaaaaaaa   * ccccaaaaaaaa   - aaaaaaaaaaaa * asdfasdfasdfasdf;
```

Do I need to put backslash in the end ?

Comment: You can break wherever you want and there’s no need for backslashes.

Comment: Thank you, what is the difference between end backslash and no end backslash?

Comment: With backslash the parser will consider it a single line internally instead of multiple ones but the end result is the same. It’s only needed in macros where they end on a newline. Normal statements end in a semicolon so newlines in the middle don’t matter.

Comment: Yes, it's safe to break anywhere, because statement ends only when semicolon is encountered.

Comment: You might want to add some parenthesis, though, to clarify the expression, because `a / b * c` is parsed as `(a / b) * c`, not `a / (b * c)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always put operators in the beginning if I have to break the line

```
int abcdefghijklmn = aaaaaaaaaaaa 
   /   bbbaaaaaaaa
   * ccccaaaaaaaa 
   - aaaaaaaaaaaa 
   * asdfasdfasdfasdf;
```